# Group by and Pivot functions giving different counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

Group by and Pivot operations give different counts.

I used Group by to get count of vehicles by City and used Pivot to get count of vehicles by Make.

```
SELECT MAKE, [AMB],[BNG],[CBE],[GBM],[KKE],[OMR],[PDR]
FROM
(
SELECT MAKE, BRANCH, COUNT(DISTINCT [VEH NO]) [VEHICLE COUNT]
FROM MAKE_MODEL_DESCRIPTION
GROUP BY MAKE, BRANCH
) X
PIVOT
(
    SUM([VEHICLE COUNT]) FOR BRANCH IN ([AMB],[BNG],[CBE],[GBM],[KKE], 
[OMR],[PDR])
) AS PVT
```

The total count I get for above Pivot query is 150.

```
select BRANCH, COUNT(distinct [VEH NO])
from MAKE_MODEL_DESCRIPTION
group by BRANCH
```

The total count I get for above GROUP BY query is 140.

Shouldn't both the same number given they are from same data source? 
Can someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not expect the counts to be the same.  The `GROUP BY` is counting distinct vehicles over *all* makes.  The `PIVOT` is counting distinct vehicles only within a *single* branch and model.

In other words, the same vehicle might be in different branches.

If you include the make, then the numbers should be the same:

```
select MAKE, BRANCH, COUNT(distinct [VEH NO])
from MAKE_MODEL_DESCRIPTION
group by MAKE, BRANCH
```